# Cannot install crystal report on WindowsServer2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-server-2012-r2

Can any one give a link to download CrystalReport for WindowsServer2012 R2.
i have tried using this link "https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads" with SP24. But its not working. Can any one give a correct link ?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of links on that page. Did you install the runtime link?

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_24.msi

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_24.msi

Also, try having the version match your local development version. (e.g. if you are developing using 13.0.23 locally, then install that runtime version on the server).

What error message are you seeing - there may be other reasons things are failing such as hard-coded report connection strings etc?